# Problems with navigating to component and call event handler at the same time (SOLVED)

Tags: reactjs, forms

I'm having problems with a form in a React component. When submitting the form with the submit button, I'd like to navigate to another component (by calling the onStepChange function inside the onClick event handler). At the same time I'd like the onSubmitAnswer event handler to be called (to check if the answer submitted is correct or wrong).
This is the whole component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Answering = ({ onStepChange }) => {
  const [userAnswer, setUserAnswer] = useState('');

  const onSubmitAnswer = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // * Correct answer, at the moment hardcoded
    const correctAnswer = 'Vienna, Austria';
    if (userAnswer === correctAnswer) {
      console.log('Correct answer')
    } else {
      console.log('Wrong answer')
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmitAnswer}>
      <div>
        <h2>We are headed to:</h2>
        <div className="select-container">
          <select
            className="select"
            id="selectInput"
            value={userAnswer}
            onChange={(event) => {
              setUserAnswer(event.target.value)
            }}>
            <option value="">The city is:</option>
            <option value="Vienna, Austria">Vienna, Austria</option>
            <option value="Helsinki, Finland">Helsinki, Finland</option>
            <option value="Oslo, Norway">Oslo, Norway</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="button-container">
        <button
          className="button"
          onClick={() => {
            onStepChange();
          }}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

When I do like this I get the warning "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" in console and can't see the console logs, but I do navigate to the other component. However, if I change the button to this instead and don't call the onStepChange function:

```js
<button type="submit" className="button">
          Submit
</button>
```

...I get the console logs, but of course then I don't navigate to the other component.

What can I do to both navigate to another component and call the onSubmitAnswer event handler? Thankful for any tips!

EDIT: Solved it by calling the onStepChange function inside the onSubmitAnswer handler instead of calling it with onClick.